# htaccess redirect without looking at the query string

Tags: .htaccess

I have these lines which let me redirect a page without changing the URL:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/samples.php [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/fruits.php
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$  /storepage.php
```

How can I do the same but this time with a query string? For example, the file `samples.php?hash=5yh4w6w46h6hy4` will still redirect to `/storepage.php` like in above without changing the URL. The file storepage.php then just lifts off the query string and shows the content related to it.

The query string is a hash so there's no way to predict its value.

Comment: you can add `QSA` (query string append) to your RewriteRule... `RewriteRule   ^(.*)$  /storepage.php [QSA]`

Comment: Are you trying to make it rewrite but *remove* the query string? I think by default the query string is appended to rewrites even without the QSA unless a `?` is in the target.

Comment: Jon is correct: by default the querystring is appended unless you change it with a ? in the target in which case you would need `[QSA]`. It should work as is.  If it does not, can you provide more details on what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have tackled this situation, please see the code below it will help you out
Please try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/samples.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fruits.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hash=5yh4w6w46h6hy4$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://example.com/storepage.php? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect the URL permanently as well as you will get your desired URL without query string